# MemoryError when reading images in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to train a CNN model in python, so I am going to load 100000 images (320x240), read their RGB values and convert to numpy matrices. However, I ran out of memory every time. Could someone tell me how to solve this problem? I think the most straightforward way would be freeing my memory.

```
segments_lst = []
lst = sorted(glob.glob('tv7789/segments/*/*/*.jpg'))
for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
    x = imageio.imread(lst[i]) 
    data = np.asarray(x)
    data = np.transpose(x, (2, 1, 0))
    segments_lst.append(data)
    gc.collect() #This does not help much.
```

Comment: why do you wish to store that many image data into ```segments_lst```?  that's bound to take a huge chunk of memory.  What do you need to do later on in the code that needs ```segments_lst```?  Can you change your code such that you process ```data``` immediately?

Comment: I second @ewong comment. Why not just save the numpy data instead of appending it to the `segments_lst`. The `gc.collect()` only cleans data that's no longer assigned to any variable, so obviously, it will not help here since your data is appended.

Comment: I tried putting all numpy arrays into one matrix, but that still requires a lot of memory, so I think the problem might be about imageio.imread()?@ewong @Wazaki

Comment: My calculations (assuming 3 bytes per pixel) suggest that you are dealing with over 20 GB of data. Do you have enough RAM to hold that in memory at once? Perhaps you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: The problem is with the approach itself. You need to temporarily store 100000 images in your RAM which, as John stated, could easily exceed 20 GB. Unless your machine can handle that, this code will not go through.